# How to use several bootstrap-modals with no bugs?

Tags: debugging, bootstrap-modal

I have a bug -

I open 1 modal

Then I open next modal from the first

Then I close second modal, but **modal background closes** too.

So when I scroll, the page scrolls and not the modal. It's wrong.

Comment: no it's not wrong, bootstrap doesn't support stacked modals.

Comment: @Shehary Yes, thank you.